# changing class to function component antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd, use-state

I tried to make this code working as functional component, but got stuck.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Tag, Input, Tooltip } from 'antd';
import { PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

class EditableTagGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tags: ['Unremovable', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3'],
    inputVisible: false,
    inputValue: '',
    editInputIndex: -1,
    editInputValue: '',
  };

  handleClose = removedTag => {
    const tags = this.state.tags.filter(tag => tag !== removedTag);
    console.log(tags);
    this.setState({ tags });
  };

  showInput = () => {
    this.setState({ inputVisible: true }, () => this.input.focus());
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  handleInputConfirm = () => {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;
    let { tags } = this.state;
    if (inputValue && tags.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      tags = [...tags, inputValue];
    }
    console.log(tags);
    this.setState({
      tags,
      inputVisible: false,
      inputValue: '',
    });
  };

  handleEditInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ editInputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  handleEditInputConfirm = () => {
    this.setState(({ tags, editInputIndex, editInputValue }) => {
      const newTags = [...tags];
      newTags[editInputIndex] = editInputValue;

      return {
        tags: newTags,
        editInputIndex: -1,
        editInputValue: '',
      };
    });
  };

  saveInputRef = input => {
    this.input = input;
  };

  saveEditInputRef = input => {
    this.editInput = input;
  };

  render() {
    const { tags, inputVisible, inputValue, editInputIndex, editInputValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {tags.map((tag, index) => {
          if (editInputIndex === index) {
            return (
              <Input
                ref={this.saveEditInputRef}
                key={tag}
                size="small"
                className="tag-input"
                value={editInputValue}
                onChange={this.handleEditInputChange}
                onBlur={this.handleEditInputConfirm}
                onPressEnter={this.handleEditInputConfirm}
              />
            );
          }

          const isLongTag = tag.length > 20;

          const tagElem = (
            <Tag
              className="edit-tag"
              key={tag}
              closable={index !== 0}
              onClose={() => this.handleClose(tag)}
            >
              <span
                onDoubleClick={e => {
                  if (index !== 0) {
                    this.setState({ editInputIndex: index, editInputValue: tag }, () => {
                      this.editInput.focus();
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }
                }}
              >
                {isLongTag ? `${tag.slice(0, 20)}...` : tag}
              </span>
            </Tag>
          );
          return isLongTag ? (
            <Tooltip title={tag} key={tag}>
              {tagElem}
            </Tooltip>
          ) : (
            tagElem
          );
        })}
        {inputVisible && (
          <Input
            ref={this.saveInputRef}
            type="text"
            size="small"
            className="tag-input"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            onBlur={this.handleInputConfirm}
            onPressEnter={this.handleInputConfirm}
          />
        )}
        {!inputVisible && (
          <Tag className="site-tag-plus" onClick={this.showInput}>
            <PlusOutlined /> New Tag
          </Tag>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EditableTagGroup />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

My code throws an error when I press "add tag" button: Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Plus setState expects 1 argument, but gets 2(2nd one is a function). I might have problems with understanding of hooks. Here is where I got stuck:

```
import { PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Tags = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    tags: ['Unremovable', 'Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3'],
    inputVisible: false,
    inputValue: '',
    editInputIndex: -1,
    editInputValue: '',
  });
  const handleClose = removedTag => {
    const tags = state.tags.filter(tag => tag !== removedTag);
    console.log(tags);
    setState({ tags });
  };

  const showInput = () => {
    setState({ inputVisible: true }, () => input.focus());
  };

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleInputConfirm = () => {
    const { inputValue } = state;
    let { tags } = state;
    if (inputValue && tags.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      tags = [...tags, inputValue];
    }
    console.log(tags);
    setState({
      tags,
      inputVisible: false,
      inputValue: '',
    });
  };

  const handleEditInputChange = e => {
    setState({ editInputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleEditInputConfirm = () => {
    setState(({ tags, editInputIndex, editInputValue }) => {
      const newTags = [...tags];
      newTags[editInputIndex] = editInputValue;

      return {
        tags: newTags,
        editInputIndex: -1,
        editInputValue: '',
      };
    });
  };
const inputRef = useRef('') 
  const saveInputRef = input => {
    inputRef.current = input;
  };
const editInput = useRef('')
  const saveEditInputRef = input => {
    editInput.current = input;
  };
  const { tags, inputVisible, inputValue, editInputIndex, editInputValue } =
      state;

  return (
    <>
    {tags.map((tag, index) => {
      if (editInputIndex === index) {
        return (
          <Input
            ref={saveEditInputRef}
            key={tag}
            size="small"
            className="tag-input"
            value={editInputValue}
            onChange={handleEditInputChange}
            onBlur={handleEditInputConfirm}
            onPressEnter={handleEditInputConfirm}
          />
        );
      }

      const isLongTag = tag.length > 20;

      const tagElem = (
        <Tag
          className="edit-tag"
          key={tag}
          closable={index !== 0}
          onClose={() => handleClose(tag)}
        >
          <span
            onDoubleClick={e => {
              if (index !== 0) {
                setState(
                  { editInputIndex: index, editInputValue: tag },
                  () => {
                    editInput.focus();
                  });
                e.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
          >
            {isLongTag ? `${tag.slice(0, 20)}...` : tag}
          </span>
        </Tag>
      );
      return isLongTag ? (
        <Tooltip title={tag} key={tag}>
          {tagElem}
        </Tooltip>
      ) : (
        tagElem
      );
    })}
    {inputVisible && (
      <Input
        ref={saveInputRef}
        type="text"
        size="small"
        className="tag-input"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onBlur={handleInputConfirm}
        onPressEnter={handleInputConfirm}
      />
    )}
    {!inputVisible && (
      <Tag className="site-tag-plus" onClick={showInput}>
        <PlusOutlined /> add tag
      </Tag>
    )}
  </>
  )
};

export default Tags;
```

Comment: Other than commenting out the second argument passed to `setState`, this code appears to render without issue. Check this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-class-to-function-component-antd-y1236). Can you recheck if you've still an issue with your code? Make sure you've killed, and restarted, any running dev servers.

Comment: The code works fine until I press "add tag" button, then I'm getting this error: "TypeError
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tags.map')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue you have is that you missed picking up that state updates in function components via the `useState` hook ***are not*** shallowly merged into state.

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does
> not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({});
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```

Because you were not merging state updates, when you clicked the add tag button the handler was removing the `tags` property from state.

```
const showInput = () => {
  setState({ inputVisible: true }); // <-- no tags property!!
};
```

## Solution

> `Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

You must manage state merges yourself. Use a functional state update to shallow copy the previous state into the next state object being returned.

```
const Tags = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    tags: ["руль", "фара", "табло", "дворники"],
    inputVisible: false,
    inputValue: "",
    editInputIndex: -1,
    editInputValue: ""
  });
  const handleClose = (removedTag) => {
    const tags = state.tags.filter((tag) => tag !== removedTag);
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, tags })); // <-- shallow copy previous state

  };

  const showInput = () => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, inputVisible: true })); // <-- shallow copy previous state
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, inputValue: e.target.value })); // <-- shallow copy previous state
  };

  const handleInputConfirm = () => {
    const { inputValue } = state;
    let { tags } = state;
    if (inputValue && tags.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      tags = [...tags, inputValue];
    }
    console.log(tags);
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state, // <-- shallow copy previous state
      tags,
      inputVisible: false,
      inputValue: ""
    }));
  };

  const handleEditInputChange = (e) => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, editInputValue: e.target.value })); // <-- shallow copy previous state
  };

  const handleEditInputConfirm = () => {
    setState(({ tags, editInputIndex, editInputValue, ...state }) => {
      const newTags = [...tags];
      newTags[editInputIndex] = editInputValue;

      return {
        ...state, // <-- shallow copy previous state
        tags: newTags,
        editInputIndex: -1,
        editInputValue: ""
      };
    });
  };

  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

> `setState expects 1 argument, but gets 2(2nd one is a function)`

The `useState` updater functions only take a single argument. If you need to run an effect *after* a state update, use an `useEffect` with appropriate dependency.

Example:

```
const showInput = () => {
  setState({ inputVisible: true });
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (state.inputVisible) {
    input.focus(); // * NOTE
  }
}, [state, input]);
```

*** Note:** In your code I didn't see where any `input` variable is declared.

[image: Edit changing-class-to-function-component-antd]

Comment: Thank you, Drew! Your solution was exactly the one I needed to success! Everything works the way it supposed to be!

Comment: @DmitryBochok Fantastic! Great to hear this works for you. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: According to the "Note": I additionally had to use ```useRef``` hook.

Comment: @DmitryBochok I figured you intended for that to be a ref and it wasn't clear if it was one of the refs that already existed or if you needed a new one, but that's why I called it out specifically since it presumably still needed to be handled in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

So, The problem occurred in this piece of code.

```
  showInput = () => {
this.setState({ inputVisible: true }, () => this.input.focus());
```

};

Problem 1: Cannot read the property of undefined. This was happening because when you were setting the new state, The whole state value was replaced by only the inputVisible property. The tags property and other ones were fully removed from the variable. So for overcoming this error you need to spread the other values of the state variable by using the Spread Operator. [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
so the new piece of code would be

```
const showInput = () => {
setState( prevState =>
  ({ ...prevState , inputVisible: true })
  //  () => input.focus()
);
```

};

Here the prevState is the previous values of the state variable.

Problem 2: By default setState can recieve only one value, that is for updating the state variable. It cannot recieve 2 arguments. If you want to do any task depending on the state change, you can use [UseEffect Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Where you just have to add the state variable inside the [Dependency Array](https://dennyscott.io/use-effect-dependency-array/) of your useEffect hooks

Answer (score 0):

Here is working piece of the code for anyone who needs!

```
import { PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Tags = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    tags: ['Unremovable', 'Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3'],
    inputVisible: false,
    inputValue: '',
    editInputIndex: -1,
    editInputValue: '',
  });

  const handleClose = removedTag => {
    const tags = state.tags.filter(tag => tag !== removedTag);
    console.log(tags);
    setState(state => ({ ...state, tags }));
  };

  const showInput = () => {
    setState(state => ({ ...state, inputVisible: true }));
  };

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    setState({ ...state, inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleInputConfirm = () => {
    const { inputValue } = state;
    let { tags } = state;
    if (inputValue && tags.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      tags = [...tags, inputValue];
    }
    console.log(tags);
    setState({
      ...state,
      tags,
      inputVisible: false,
      inputValue: '',
    });
  };

  const handleEditInputChange = e => {
    setState(state => ({ ...state, editInputValue: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleEditInputConfirm = () => {
    setState(({ tags, editInputIndex, editInputValue, ...state }) => {
      const newTags = [...tags];
      newTags[editInputIndex] = editInputValue;

      return {
        ...state,
        tags: newTags,
        editInputIndex: -1,
        editInputValue: '',
      };
    });
  };

  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const saveInputRef = input => {
    inputRef.current = input;
  };
  const editInput = useRef(null);
  const saveEditInputRef = input => {
    editInput.current = input;
  };
  const { tags, inputVisible, inputValue, editInputIndex, editInputValue } =
    state;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.inputVisible) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [state, saveInputRef]);

  return (
    <>
      {tags.map((tag, index) => {
        if (editInputIndex === index) {
          return (
            <Input
              ref={saveEditInputRef}
              key={tag}
              size="small"
              className="tag-input"
              value={editInputValue}
              onChange={handleEditInputChange}
              onBlur={handleEditInputConfirm}
              onPressEnter={handleEditInputConfirm}
            />
          );
        }

        const isLongTag = tag.length > 20;

        const tagElem = (
          <Tag
            className="edit-tag"
            key={tag}
            closable={index !== 0}
            onClose={() => handleClose(tag)}
          >
            <span
              onDoubleClick={e => {
                if (index !== 0) {
                  setState(state => ({
                    ...state,
                    editInputIndex: index,
                    editInputValue: tag,
                  }));
                  e.preventDefault();
                }
              }}
            >
              {isLongTag ? `${tag.slice(0, 20)}...` : tag}
            </span>
          </Tag>
        );
        return isLongTag ? (
          <Tooltip title={tag} key={tag}>
            {tagElem}
          </Tooltip>
        ) : (
          tagElem
        );
      })}
      {inputVisible && (
        <Input
          ref={saveInputRef}
          type="text"
          size="small"
          className="tag-input"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          onBlur={handleInputConfirm}
          onPressEnter={handleInputConfirm}
        />
      )}
      {!inputVisible && (
        <Tag className="site-tag-plus" onClick={showInput}>
          <PlusOutlined /> add tag
        </Tag>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Tags;
```